# Automate Document Checks

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, automation, document

this is sort of a weird/complicated question but I thought id ask.

So during the sign up process for my app (I am using flutter and firebase for backend), people have to submit certain documents such as a resume and other official documents. My question was assuming the documents have a standard layout, is there any way to verify that it is the correct type of document automatically? So someone couldn't fake a document and sign up for the app.

I wanted to make it in a way so I wouldn't personally have to go through each document and make sure its the right one.

If anyone has any ideas please ping me and let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It sounds like an interesting project but SO is not a code writing service - we can assist with existing code you've attempted. Also, the question is pretty vague; what would make a document *the right one* for example. How would one know the difference between a *fake* and a *real* document? Write some code and when you get stuck, post it here along with your troubleshooting steps and we'll take a look.